# Save file after it is imported to app

Tags: ios, swift, import

I have an iOS app that I would like to save a file that is given to it when a user on Safari downloads a file and chooses "Import with *MYAPP*"

I've already got the part where it recognizes that my app supports the file down but when I choose to open the file with the app, it isn't being added.

There is really not much documentation on this, or at least nothing recent. Here is my failed attempt at saving the file:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?, openURL Url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    let encrypteddata = NSData(contentsOf: Url as URL)
    if(encrypteddata != nil){

        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let paths = (NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString).appendingPathComponent("test.ipa")
        print(paths)
        fileManager.createFile(atPath: paths as String, contents: encrypteddata as Data?, attributes: nil)

    }
return true

}
```

Update:

It seems that the files are stored in the Documents/Inbox directory in the app's sandbox container. How can I list all of the files and read their contents?

Comment: Where does this delegate method come from? It's not a part of `UIApplicationDelegate`. By the way: Don't use `NSString`, `NSData`, `NSURL` in Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have URL from

```
optional func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, 
    sourceApplication: String?, 
           annotation: Any) -> Bool
```

method, you can access file from this URL or you can find all documents from FileManager as below shown

```
let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
do {
    let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
    print(directoryContents)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

This will list all your files from document directory.